# Http Request's Content Is Always Null When Making Request From Xamarin

Tags: c#, azure, http, facebook-graph-api, xamarin

I am making an app with Xamarin Forms and Azure. I am authenticating with Google and Facebook.

When requesting user's data, I use a HttpClient and make a request. Requesting from Google works fine but Facebook always returns null.

I have tested the Url in Postman with the same access token, it returns the correct data.

The Url is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/?fields=name,picture,locale,link,devices,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=
```

This returns:

```
{
    "name": "Reece Russell",
    "picture": {
        "data": {
            "height": 50,
            "is_silhouette": false,
            "url": "https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?asid=2139651619601242&height=50&width=50&ext=1526558014&hash=AeSKoNrLS6O4UmMV",
            "width": 50
        }
    },
    "locale": "en_US",
    "link":  "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/YXNpZADpBWEhTLXBnRko4LWlBRUVzc0RBZAXhsc3R1eXpNNGZAxNmJMaXhWT013WTFCMVNnOFpLNE1jblh3dWJjLUwyRDhLQ0QyOHh6NmxnVGNyX2REMU9vUzNYTHFKNjlfN0J5R0lVbkV5ZA1V4aDRBZAVNDMnpwS0EZD/",
    "devices": [
        {
            "hardware": "iPhone",
            "os": "iOS"
        }
    ],
    "first_name": "Reece",
    "last_name": "Russell",
    "id": "2139651619601242"
}
```

But when making this request from Xamarin Forms using a HttpClient it always returns null.

The code I am using is below. I have also tried many ways of making the request including making the request from my server, which gets the correct data from FaceBook but returns null when I request from my server it still returns null.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
{
    string url = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me/?fields=name,picture,locale,link,devices,email,first_name,last_name&access_token=" + Settings.AccessToken;
    string json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
    FacebookUserProfile profile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FacebookUserProfile>(json);
    profile.PhotoUrl = profile.Picture.Data.Url;
    profile.Name = profile.FirstName + " " + profile.LastName;
    return profile;
}
```

Comment: Is the `await client.GetStringAsync(url);` already  null?

Comment: @Freggar yes. I have tried using await GetAsync(URL); this returns a HTTP response message which has a 200 status code but the content is also null.

Comment: try not passing NativeMessageHandler

Comment: @Tolulope I added NativeMessageHandler to see if it would have an effect, but I still get null